# checkout commit with different submodule setup does not work properly

Tags: git, git-submodules

In one of our git repo, there was a submodule added at some point. Now, whenever I checkout a state of the git repo, where the submodule was not yet there it does not properly "remove" the submodule. It seems to be in a state, where the submodule is half there, half not.

I also noticed, that the submodule is no longer preset in `.gitmodules` but its folders in `path/to/submodule` and in `.git/modules` still exist.

I tried at least the following things:

`git status` => Untracked files: path/to/submodule

`git reset --hard` => unchanged

`git submodule foreach reset --hard` => unchanged

`git clean -d -f` => `Skipping repository path/to/submodule`

`git submodule update --init` => unchanged

But until now I did not get it solved. Of course I could manually delete these folders, but I want it to work automatically, when I switch commits, as this is also an issue on our CI (Jenkins).

Any help / hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to run `git clean` with double `-f` arguments. From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) (emphasis mine):

> -f
>   --force
>
> If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to 
>   false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless
>   given -f, -n or -i. **Git will refuse to delete directories with .git
>   sub directory or file unless a second -f is given.** This affects also
>   git submodules where the storage area of the removed submodule under
>   .git/modules/ is not removed until -f is given twice.

So the correct command is: `git clean -d -f -f`

Comment: Thx so much, I've never heard of something, where you had to give an option param twice! But learning never stops :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's really useful code. I was charging with this git untracked problem and this is the correct command **git clean -d -f -f**